# Get an array field from multiple documents and merge elements into one object

Tags: javascript, mongodb, aggregation-framework

For example, I have a `users` collection. Each user document has `posts` array, containing their posts. I want to query this collection like so:

Get 2 posts starting at index `Nstart` and ending at `Nend` from each user in username array: `['user1', 'user2']` and return a merged array of posts, ordered by ascending of post.postedOn int.

If this is the collection:

```
{
  username: "user1",
  posts: [
    { id: 1, text: "123" ... },
    { id: 2, text: "456" ... },
    { id: 3, text: "789" ... },
    ...
  ]
},
{
  username: "user2",
  posts: [
    { id: 1, text: "abc" ... },
    { id: 2, text: "def" ... },
    { id: 3, text: "ghi" ... },
    ...
  ]
}
...
```

I want to get this:

```
{
  posts: {
    { id: 1, text: "123" ... },
    { id: 2, text: "456" ... },
    { id: 1, text: "abc" ... },
    { id: 2, text: "def" ... },
  }
}
```

I have tried using `aggregate` multiple times. this is one of my queries:

```
db.getCollection("users").aggregate([{ $match: { username: { $in: ["admin", "admin2"] } } }, { $project: { posts: 1 } }])
```

I get two user objects, each containing all of their posts, not one posts array that I can manipulate later.

The final result I'm trying to achieve is this:

#### Inputs

- users: `['user1', 'user2']`
- starting posts index: `4`
- ending posts index: `8`

#### Result

Array of posts by selected users. Total count of 8 (id 4-8 from each user).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This requires the usage of the aggregation operators [$slice](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/slice/index.html) and [$push](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/push/index.html) to select and add the required post elements (by index) in to an array, respectively.

For example the `posts` collection has three documents (I have omitted the `_id` field here):

```
{
       "username" : "user2",
       "posts" : [
               {
                       "id" : 1,
                       "text" : "123"
               },
               {
                       "id" : 2,
                       "text" : "456"
               },
               {
                       "id" : 3,
                       "text" : "789"
               },
               {
                       "id" : 4,
                       "text" : "000"
               }
       ]
}
{
       "username" : "user1",
       "posts" : [
               {
                       "id" : 1,
                       "text" : "abc"
               },
               {
                       "id" : 2,
                       "text" : "def"
               },
               {
                       "id" : 3,
                       "text" : "ghi"
               },
               {
                       "id" : 4,
                       "text" : "zzz"
               }
       ]
}
{
        "username" : "user99",
        "posts" : [ ]
}
```

**In the mongo shell:**

```
> var users = [ "user1", "user2" ]
> var startIx = 1, noOfElements = 2

> db.posts.aggregate([ 
  { $project: { _id: 0, username: 1, posts: 1, usersMatch: { $in: [ "$username",  users ] } } },
  { $match: { usersMatch: true } },
  { $addFields: { posts: { $slice: [ "$posts", startIx, noOfElements ] } } },
  { $group: { _id: null, postsOfSelectedUsers: { $push: "$posts"} } },
  { $project: { _id: 0, selectedUsers: users, postsOfSelectedUsers: 1 } } 
])
```

**The Output:**

```
{
        "postsOfSelectedUsers" : [
                [
                        {
                                "id" : 2,
                                "text" : "456"
                        },
                        {
                                "id" : 3,
                                "text" : "789"
                        }
                ],
                [
                        {
                                "id" : 2,
                                "text" : "def"
                        },
                        {
                                "id" : 3,
                                "text" : "ghi"
                        }
                ]
        ],
        "selectedUsers" : [
                "user1",
                "user2"
        ]
}
```

**NOTE**: This is a solution, but this can be refined or re-worked upon (I think).

Comment: That's exactly what I wanted. Thank you.